# Convert character to date or date time vector without knowing its origin or format

Tags: r

I suspect that I have a datetime vector like:

```
timestamp = c(4273639583, 4273639583, 4273639583, 4273639583, 4273639583)
```

how can I convert it to datetime if I do not know for sure that it is a datetime vector or just date. Also I do not know its origin.

```
timestamp <- as.POSIXct(timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz=Sys.timezone())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the package `anytime` with [anytime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anytime/versions/0.3.9/topics/anytime) function like this:

```r
dt<-structure(list(timestamp = c(4273639583, 4273639583, 4273639583, 
                                 4273639583, 4273639583)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(anytime)
anytime(dt$timestamp)
#> [1] "2105-06-05 12:06:23 CEST" "2105-06-05 12:06:23 CEST"
#> [3] "2105-06-05 12:06:23 CEST" "2105-06-05 12:06:23 CEST"
#> [5] "2105-06-05 12:06:23 CEST"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>